# How to use execute in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, execute

I don't know how to use `execute` in Retrofit.

I used call.enqueue in retrofit for getting address from openstreetmap. but I got error for using it in main thread. I should use execute in `AsyncTask` method but I don't know how use it? would you mind please sending me an example about  `execute`?

Comment: `execute` submits and fetches the request synchronously but `enqueue`  returns immediately and sends the request in a background thread. So, if you want to use `execute` you should first start a new thread and then call `execute` as in Android doing network calls in the main thread is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you Frogatto, I did this. but now I got this error. Can't create handler inside thread Thread[AsyncTask #2,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare(). what should I do now?

Comment: What do you want to do? rest API call? file download? what?

Comment: You can look at this article- https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests

Comment: It seems you are trying to access main thread/ UI thread from background thread (doInBackground). If you are doing so you need to do that in onPostExecute method of AsyncTask.